# Read only Pandas dataset in Dask Distributed

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-distributed

**TL;DR**
I want to allow workers to use a scattered Pandas Dataframe, but not allow them to mutate any data. Look below for sample code. Is this possible? (or is this a pure Pandas question?)

**Full question**
I'm reading a Pandas Dataframe, and scattering it to the workers. I then use this future when I submit new tasks, and store it in a Variable for easy access.

Sample code:

```
df = pq.read_table('/data/%s.parq' % dataset).to_pandas()
df = client.scatter(df, broadcast=True, direct=True)
v = Variable('dataset')
v.set(df)
```

When I submit a job I use:

```
def top_ten_x_based_on_y(dataset, column):
    return dataset.groupby(dataset['something'])[column].mean().sort_values(ascending=False)[0:10].to_dict()

a = client.submit(top_ten_x_based_on_y, df, 'a_column')
```

Now, I want to run 10-20 QPS on this dataset which all workers have in memory (data < RAM) but I want to protect against accidental changes of the dataset, such as one worker "corrupting" it's own memory which can lead to inconsistencies. Preferably raising an exception on trying to modify.

The data set is roughly 2GB.

I understand this might be problematic since a Pandas Dataframe itself is not immutable (although a Numpy array can be made to).

**Other ideas**:

1. Copy the dataset on each query, but 2GB copy takes time even in RAM (roughly 1.4 seconds)
2. Devise a way to hash a dataframe (probematic in itself, even though `hash_pandas_object` now exists), and check before and after (or every minute) if dataframe is the same as expected. Running hash_pandas_object takes roughly 5 seconds.

Comment: Nice question!  I also appreciate the `tl;dr` section :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Dask currently offers no additional features on top of Python to avoid mutation in this way.  Dask just runs Python functions, and those Python functions can do anything they like.

Your suggestions of copying or checking before running operations seems sensible to me.

You might also consider raising this as a question or feature request to Pandas itself.

Comment: Good point, they've declined for Pandas 1.x (out-of-scope, https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/16567) but I've raised a ticket for pandas 2.x (https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas2/issues/75)